# Opening a paper-dialog on click on paper-input

Tags: html, css, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am trying to open [`<paper-dialog>`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-dialog) on a click from [`<paper-input>`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-input), but I want to ignore clicks on the `<paper-input>`'s floating label. I tried to disable the label's `pointer-events`, using the CSS mixin below, but it seems to have no effect. How can I accomplish this?

*HTML template:*

```
<paper-input class="select" on-click="displayTimezone" 
   value="{{timeZone}}"  
   readonly
   label="Select Time Zone">
   <iron-icon icon="expand-more" suffix></iron-icon>
</paper-input>
<paper-dialog id="timezoneDialog"></paper-dialog>
```

*CSS mixin:*

```
paper-input {
   --paper-input-container-label-focus {
      pointer-events: none !important;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`paper-input-container`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-input/elements/paper-input-container).

```
<paper-input-container>
  <label slot="label">Select Time Zone</label>
  <iron-input slot="input" on-click="displayTimezone" bind-value="{{timeZone}}">
    <input>
  </iron-input>
  <iron-icon icon="expand-more" slot="suffix"></iron-icon>
</paper-input-container>
```

To get the material design you can style with the `--paper-input-container-shared-input-style` mixin.

```
<style>
  :host {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 0;
    --paper-input-container-shared-input-style: {
      position: relative; /* to make a stacking context */
      outline: none;
      box-shadow: none;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      background: transparent;
      border: none;
      color: var(--paper-input-container-input-color, var(--primary-text-color));
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      text-align: inherit;
      vertical-align: bottom;
      @apply --paper-font-subhead;
    };
    @apply --paper-input-container;

  }
  input { border:none; width: 100%;}
  input:focus { outline: none;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check the [event target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) to process only clicks from the inner `<input>` (ignoring clicks from the label or the underline):

```
displayTimezone: function(e) {
  // open dialog only for <input> clicks
  if (e.target.localName === 'input') {
    this.$.timezoneDialog.open();
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/eGpPLg?editors=1011)